# golang tls как определить клиентский сертификат

Tags: golang, ssl

Задача:
сделать сервер, принимающий TCP-подключение через защищенный канал с авторизацией по сертификату.
В стандартную библиотеку Go входит пакет для работы с TLS https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/tls/
в нем можно задать корневой сертификат, поставить настройку чтобы принимались только правильно подписанные сертификаты, но ни в документации, ни в API ни в примерах я не нашел способа узнать с каким именно сертификатом подключился клиент для его авторизации уже во внутренней логике сервера.

Подойдут варианты получения клиентского сертификата целиком или его common name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

twotwotwo подсказал решение на англоязычном ресурсе.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31751764/get-remote-ssl-certificate-in-golang

Сведения о сертификатах другой стороны можно получить так:
conn.ConnectionState().PeerCertificates[0]